# MS-Access - Setting parameters for pass-through query

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access

I have a pass-through query (for SQL Server) in Access which works with explicit values.  For a non-pass-though query, I just use the visual editor to create parameters for the affected columns.

Is it possible to do the equivalent with a pass-through query or must I assemble the query with VBA (as mentioned in another post)?

TIA,

Paolo

Comment: if the sql is simple enough you can have a locla query with all your "linked" tables for design purpose. Copy the SQL if you want to execute the query. Otherwise you must use the back-end-server mssql/mysql compatible queryeditor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot. It would be once possible with ODBCDirect workspace but that was removed since Access 2010. Therefore, for pass-through queries, you would have to concatenate SQL.

A possible alternative is to use ADO which allow you to create parameters and thus construct a command and execute it. Note that your project doesn't have to be limited to only DAO; you can use both DAO and ADO, leveraging what works best for your requirements.